# Reverse a number by converting it to a string USING toString

Tags: javascript

```js
function reverse(num) {
  let newwarray = [];
  let temparray = [];
  var x = num.toString();
  for (var i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--); {
    newwarray += x[i]
  }
  return newwarray;
}
document.write(reverse(3456))
```

So the title basically says it all. The result is undefined and I can't find the problem by using Console.

Comment: To add elements to an array use `.push`. `+=` won't work

Comment: Yeah I used push but the result is the same, undefined. Trying to find the bug here.

Comment: @JiangYuxin Remove the semi-colon after your for-loop. Otherwise the block after it will not be seen as part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two little mistakes you've made.

The first one is the semicolon at the end of the line here:

```
 for (var i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--);
```

Due to that, the stuff in the brackets in the following lines, is *not the loops body*. It's a seperate statement. The loops body is that single semicolon `;`.

Therefore what happens is that the loop runs, till the end condition is met (when `i` is -1), then the block behind it runs, and does:

```
{
 newwarray+=x[i]
}
```

And the `-1` position of `x` is `undefined`. Now if you add an array and `undefined`, both the array and undefined will be casted to a string (an empty array is turned into an empty string), and you end up with `"undefined"`.

To make it working, remove the semicolon, and `.push` to the array:

```
for (var i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  newwarray.push(x[i]);
}
```

---

As a sidenote, the first mistake was only possible because you used `var`, which declares `i` not only in the loop's body, but in *the whole function*. I strongly recommend using `let` to spot such errors more easily:

```
 for(let i = 1; i < 0; );
 {
   console.log(i); // ReferenceError: i is not defined
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have to reverse the number then you can make use of `Array.prototype.reverse` function by doing a trick

```js
function reverse(num){
  let arr = num.toString().split("");
  arr = arr.reverse();
  return arr.join("")
}
document.write(reverse(3456)); //6543
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it reverses the number by making a new array

```
var number = 12345;
var stringArray = number.toString().split("");
var generatedReverse = [];

 /* Loop through array of numbers */
for(i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){
    var rev = stringArray[stringArray.length - 1 - i];
    generatedReverse.push(rev);
}
var reverseFinal = generatedReverse.join("");
document.write(reverseFinal);
```